# View column names and their indices in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataset where I need to remove a sizeable chunk of columns, so I want to view the list of columns I have and their indices and then pass them in to a drop command with slice:

`df.drop(df.columns[25:100], axis=1, inplace=True)`

However I need to first see the indices for all the columns. On another dataset I was able to see this using `df.info()`, but on this occasion I just see a summary of the data.
Can someone advise how to do this or an alternative way?

Comment: pd.Series(df.columns)

Comment: `df.info(verbose=True)`?

Comment: or `list(enumerate(df.columns))`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this could help:

```
{k:i for i,k in enumerate(df.columns)}
```

This will produce a dictionary of each column and its index.
Additionally, if you want to query the index of specific columns:

```
[list(df.columns).index(col) for col in COLUMN_NAMES]
```

Where COLUMN_NAMES are the columns you want to find.